# Visual Studio ;New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(strConString); code fails - what am I missing?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, database-connection

I am trying to build a Visual Studio 19, Visual Basic database application using the Windows Forms App (.NET Framework) template. The template wizard works well and leads me to make a connection with the database. The app.config file is shown below.

````
```

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Paint.MySettings.PaintDBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\PaintDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```
````

Note that both the connectionstring and providername are defined but that the latter does not include "Provider=" which is often cited as a requirement in the literature that I have read.

My code then moves on to a Form that makes use of the database. One of the first lines of code in the Form_Load subroutine is:

```
`strConString = My.Settings.PaintDBConnectionString`
```

When the code is executed the value of strConString is

```
"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\PaintDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True".
```

Note that there is no reference to "Provider=System.Data.SqlClient".

When I try to establish the connection in the form using:

```
conDB = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(strConString)
```

I get an Exception Unhandled message thus:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString.  An example would be, 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;'.'
```

If, however, I use the following code:

```
Using conDB As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = My.Settings.PaintDBConnectionString}
            conDB.Open()
```

The connection is made and the code moves on to the next line which is:

```
   da = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, strConString)
            da.Fill(ds, "Manufacturers")
```

This fails on the '.Fill' command with the same error as above.

System.ArgumentException: 'An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString.  An example would be, 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;'.'

If I try to programmatically correct strConString to what I think it should be the following:

```
strConString = "Provider=System.Data.SqlClient;" + strConString
```

then the code fails again at the '.Fill' command but this time with an Exception Thrown message as follows:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The 'System.Data.SqlClient' provider is not registered on the local machine.'
```

I have seen articles in stackoverflow on both of these messages and have tried to follow the solutions but without success.

Can anyone throw any light on how I can correct my workings. I hope the additional information I have provided may help your thinking.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `SqlDataAdapter` instead of `OleDbDataAdapter`?

Comment: Use the Data.SqlClient namespace for all of it.  OleDb is a whole different technology

Comment: What kind of database do you use? Check the connection string's difference between [sqlserver](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) and [access](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are to use Access as Database, use this for your reference:

```
       //Declaration of connection
       Public sConnection As String = ""
       Public Connection As OleDbConnection 

       sConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & filepath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES"""
    Connection = New OleDbConnection(sConnection)
    Connection.Open()

    Dim sSelect As String = "select * from [table$]"
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sSelect, Connection)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
```

If you are to use SQL as Database, use this for your reference:

```
    //Declaration of connection
    Public sqlcon As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Server =*servername*;User Id=*userid*;Password=*password*;Integrated Security=false;Database=*dbname*;")

    Dim str as String = "SELECT * FROM table"
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(str, sqlcon)
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        Dim dt As New DataSet

        da.Fill(ds, "TableDetails")
```